# How to combine multirow into a row with multi-condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to combine rows into single row with condition. The condition base on telephone and email. If email and telephone are the same then entity and account will be combine into a row .
I can not find logic to this problem. Any idea? For example:

Current data:

```
entity  phone               email account_no
   E01     22 minhkhang@gmail.com
   E02     33  hoangyen@gmail.com
   E03     55    tmai@hotmail.com
   E04     66   thuthao@gmail.com
   E05     77    lamanh@gmail.com        M05
   E06     88    tuantu@gmail.com        M06
   E07    100    maidao@gmail.com
           11 minhkhang@gmail.com        M01
           44  hoangyen@gmail.com        M02
           55  thanhmai@gmail.com        M03
           66   tthao@hotmail.com        M04
           99 hoangkien@gmail.com        M07
```

Result I want:

```
entity account_no
              M07
   E02        M02
   E05        M05
   E07
   E01        M01
   E03        M03
   E04        M04
   E06        M06
```

Comment: You need to give us a minimal, runnable example, including all your Python code.

Comment: You wrote *"If email and telephone are the same"* but with your output, it seems to be "email **OR** telephone".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `merge` on `phone` column then on `email` column. Combine the two new dataframes and remove duplicates:

```
phone = pd.merge(df[['entity', 'phone']].dropna(),
                 df[['account_no', 'phone']].dropna(),
                 how='outer', on='phone') \
          .drop(columns='phone')

email = pd.merge(df[['entity', 'email']].dropna(),
                 df[['account_no', 'email']].dropna(),
                 how='outer', on='email') \
          .drop(columns='email')

out = phone.combine_first(email).drop_duplicates('account_no').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  entity account_no
0    E01        M01
1    E02        M02
2    E03        M03
3    E04        M04
4    E05        M05
5    E06        M06
6    E07
9               M07
```

Comment: @TienVu. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @Corralien . It worked for my code